# How does event binding work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I was prepared to ask how to bind (jQuery) events in JavaScript prototypes. So I created a snippet expecting it not to work as I intended.

Yet it did, and since I don't want the snippet to go to waste I will instead ask another question :)

How come this works? Does the `initEvent()` method create a property of the event inside the object - did not find it in `console.log( test );`?

```js
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

  function hex(x) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }
  return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

function TestPrototype(container) {
    this.container = container;
  } // TestPrototype 'constructor'

TestPrototype.prototype.initEvent = function() {
    var _that = this;
    $("body").on("click", this.container, function() {
      var rgb = $(_that.container).css("background-color");
      var hex = rgb2hex(rgb).toUpperCase();
      if (hex == "#FF0000")
        $(_that.container).css("background", "#0000FF");
      else
        $(_that.container).css("background", "#FF0000");
    });
  } // initEvent

var test = new TestPrototype("#test");
test.initEvent();
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" title="Click on me">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't quite get what your question is. Why wouldn't it work? You're basically just passing around the string `"#test"` (`this.container === _that.container === '#test'`).

Comment: I thought that once the initEvent(); method has been run, the click event would not be triggered ( thought it would be collected by GC or something, if I did not specify something simillar to a this.bindEvent ).

Comment: @Yoshi Yup, that is what i thought as well, there is nothing special here.
@Igor You are not even creating an event, `initEvent()` is used to init an event which was created with `document.createEvent`. You have just added a method `initEvent` to the prototype of `TestPrototype`, which will then add an `onclick` handler using jquery.

Comment: So once I specify a `$("body").on("click", etc.. )` jQuery internally stores the event wherever I initialize it?

Comment: As David said, at the moment you're not creating or storing any events anywhere. You're only *attaching* an event **listener** to a predefined event (which will then be triggered by the environment (browser)).

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I'm starting to understand what's going on. Voted to close